# Jquery validation checking if value exists in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, validation

As the title says I'm trying to check via jquery validation plugin if value for Patch_No exists. I read through many other similar topics and that's how I figured the code but it seems not to be working although there are no errors.
I'm pretty sure DBconnection.php works hence I'm using it in another file to input data.

```
<?php
include 'DBconnection.php';
$patch = $_REQUEST['patch'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM champions WHERE Patch_No ='$patch'";
$conn->query($sql);
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($num>0){
    echo 'false';
}
else{
    echo 'true';
}
?>
```

Here is also the jquery validation code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#first_form').validate({
            rules: {
                patch: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    remote: {
                        url: "checkpatch.php",
                        type: "post"
                        }
                    }
                },
            messages: {
                patch: {
                    required: "Please enter patch version.",
                    remote: "This Patch already exists."
                    }

                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And last but not least the actual form in php

```
echo '<form id="first_form" action="index.php" method="POST" style="border: 0; margin: 0;">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$formid.'" name="formid">';
                echo '<input type="text" name="patch" placeholder="PATCH e.g. 4.20" required autofocus><br/>';
                echo '<input placeholder="Number of Champions" value="1" type="number" name="champ_number" min="1" max="99" required><br/>';
                echo '<input type="submit" value="next">';
            echo '</form>';
```

**EDIT** 
DBconnection.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "patches";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: BTW, your code is insecure. See PHP's mysqli_/PDO APIs, and prepared statements!

Comment: I'm learning mysql and php right now so after I'm done with functionality I'll move to security

Comment: Strongly suggest you reverse your priorities!!

Comment: change the code to `if($num>0){
    echo json_encode(false);
}
else{
        echo json_encode(true);
}` and see if this makes any difference.

Comment: You have a `mysqli` connection and using `mysql` function. Change the mysql functions to mysqli compatible one.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp

I've changed it to mysqli_num_rows no luck still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM champions WHERE Patch_No ='".$patch."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$num = $result->num_rows;
```

Comment: for some reason it worked could you explain it to me?

Comment: read this:http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php even if you are not getting let me know.

Comment: and avoid using mysql use PDO or mysqli because mysql is deprecated and  you will be getting warnings if you will enable error_reporting().

Comment: @Suchitkumar, Can you help me in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536181/jquery-validation-message-not-displaying-while-checking-the-email-exist-or-not

Answer (score 0):

These lines are surly bad. You want to fetch a string... Use this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM champions WHERE Patch_No ='$patch'";
$conn->query($sql);
$num = mysql_num_rows($conn);
```

You need to fetch your `$conn`, that is the resource, not `$sql`.

**NOTES**

- Do not use mysql functions, they are deprecated.
- Avoid sql injections by escaping your variables in your query, or use prepared statements.

Comment: I changed source to $conn nothing happens still unfortunately

Comment: Edit your question, and show me, whats in `DBconnection.php`