# jQuery validation message not displaying while checking the email exist or not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I am using jQuery validator for validation the form.I am checking the email id is already exist or not in the database which is working perfectly. I am getting output in the `Network->Response tab`.

The issue is I am not able to display that validation error message in the form. I also set the message rule but that is not displaying.

Would you help me out in this?
Check below image.
[image]

**Form**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="demo1.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name"><br />
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"><br />
  <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="mobile no"><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script  src="assets/js/test.js"></script>
```

**test.js**

```
// When the browser is ready...
  $(function() {
    $("form[name='form1']").validate({
      // Specify the validation rules
      rules: {
        name:{
          required: true,
          minlength: 3,
          maxlength: 50
        },
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true,
          remote: {
            url: "process?key=emailalready_register",
              type: "post"
            }
          },
          mobile: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 10
          }
        },
        messages: {
          email: {remote: "Email already in use!"}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
      }           
    });    
  });
```

**Process.php**

```
function emailalready_register($conn){
  if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email =$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
    $sql_check_email="SELECT email FROM register WHERE email =?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_check_email);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($email);
    $rows = $stmt->fetch();
    $total_rows = count($rows);
    if( $total_rows > 0 ){
      echo 'Already exsist';
    } else {
      echo 'Not exsist';
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$(function() {
    $("form[name='form1']").validate({
      // Specify the validation rules
      rules: {
        name:{
          required: true,
          minlength: 3,
          maxlength: 50
        },
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true,
          remote: "process?key=emailalready_register",

          },

          mobile: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 10
          }
        },
        messages: {
          email: {remote: "Email already in use!"}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
      }           
    });    
  });
```

**Process .php**

```
function emailalready_register($conn){
  if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email =$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
    $sql_check_email="SELECT email FROM register WHERE email =?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_check_email);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($email);
    $rows = $stmt->fetch();
    $total_rows = count($rows);
    if( $total_rows > 0 ){
      echo 'false';
    } else {
      echo 'true';
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  }   
}
```

Comment: Welcome @NarendraVerma :)

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file is supposed to return `true` or `false`.

Comment: You mean to say I have to use echo 'true' or echo 'false'in my process page? I tried that If I used then validation not working.

Comment: try adding `async: false` after `type: post`

Comment: Not true. `If the serverside response is a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead", this string will be displayed as a custom error message in place of the default.` https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: @styl3r, It's not working, Page is redirecting demo1.php after clicked on submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a div in your `html` and target to output the message, like so:

```
<div class="messages"></div>
```

Comment: What is that `remote` validation for?

Comment: You can check https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/ which is suggested by Daerik

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The url given in your email check is wrong.

Change your **test.js** to this:

```
$(function() {
    $("form[name='form1']").validate({
      // Specify the validation rules
      rules: {
        name:{
          required: true,
          minlength: 3,
          maxlength: 50
        },
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true,
          remote: {
            url: "process.php",
           type: "post",
           dataFilter: function(data) {
                      var json = JSON.parse(data);
                      return "\"" + json.msg + "\"";
           }
            }
          },
          mobile: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 10
          }
        },
        messages: {
          email: {remote: "email is in use!"}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
      }           
    });    
  });
```

Change your **process.php** to this:

```
<?php 

    /* if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        //make your $conn available here
        $email =$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
        $sql_check_email="SELECT email FROM register WHERE email =?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_check_email);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email);
        $rows = $stmt->fetch();
        $total_rows = count($rows);
        if( $total_rows > 0 ){
            echo json_encode(array("msg"=>"Already exists"));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("msg"=>"Not exists"));
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
 */

echo json_encode(array("msg"=>"Already exists"));
```

**Note:** this is for demo of the message so it will always show `"Already exists"`. **comment** the last line and **un-comment** the rest of  **process.php** and check.Please look for the **process.php** code and check if it is working properly or not.